# При установке self-hosted Sentry не запускается контейнер Postgres

Tags: docker, sentry

Всем привет.  Я пытаюсь установить self hosted Sentry 24.2.0 на Винду с помощью WSL2 (Ubuntu 22) но контейнер Postgres не поднимается. в логах можно видеть:

```
Container sentry-self-hosted-postgres-1  Started
Waiting for postgres server, 5 remaining attempts...
Waiting for postgres server, 4 remaining attempts...
Waiting for postgres server, 3 remaining attempts...
Waiting for postgres server, 2 remaining attempts...
Waiting for postgres server, 1 remaining attempts...
```

и в конце ошибка :

```
dependency failed to start: container sentry-self-hosted-postgres-1 is unhealthy
Error in install/set-up-and-migrate-database.sh:13.
'$dcr web shell -c "
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS sentry_groupedmessage DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS sentry_groupedmessage_project_id_id_515aaa7e_uniq;')
  cursor.execute('DROP INDEX IF EXISTS sentry_groupedmessage_project_id_id_515aaa7e_uniq;')
"' exited with status 1
-> install.sh:main:35
```

В самом  контейнере sentry-self-hosted-postgres-1 ошибка выглядит следующим образом:

```
2024-03-04 11:30:56 exec /opt/sentry/postgres-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось , что  большая часть sh, даже если их не открывать содержит виндовсовские регулярки. вот это помогло  find scripts -type f -exec sed -i 's/\r//g' {} ; и postgres поднялся норм.